# Split string into columns, and then assign values to correct variables

Tags: r, split

How could I split strings from a df column to multiple columns, and then assign values to the right variable.

In my example, Q1 to Q4 are variable names, and 'Neutral' and so on, are possible answers.

My problem mainly lies with the possible 'NAs'

```
A <- 'Q1:\r\nNeutral\r\nQ2:\r\nTotally Disagree\r\nQ3:\r\nTotally Agree'
B <- 'Q1:\r\nNeutral\r\nQ2:\r\nNeutral\r\nQ3:\r\nNeutral'
C <- 'Q1:\r\nNeutral\r\nQ3:\r\nNeutral'
D <- ''

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(A,B,C,D)))

AllAnswers <- c('Neutral','Totally Disagree', 'Totally Agree', 'Neutral', 'Neutral', 'Neutral', 'Neutral', 'Neutral', '', '', '', '')

DesiredDf <- data.frame(matrix(AllAnswers, nrow = 4, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest :

```
separate(df,V1,c("a","b","c"),sep='\r\n(?=Q)') %>%
   mutate(id=row_number()) %>% 
   gather(k,v,-id) %>%
   separate(v,c("v1","v2"),":\r\n") %>% 
   select(-k) %>% 
   filter(!is.na(v2)) %>% 
   spread(v1,v2)
```

But there seems to be a problem in your 'DesiredDF', here is my output :

```
  #id      Q1               Q2            Q3
  #1  1 Neutral Totally Disagree Totally Agree
  #2  2 Neutral          Neutral       Neutral
  #3  3 Neutral             <NA>       Neutral
```

In 'df' there is no Q2 for the third line :

```
  #                                                                 V1
  #1 Q1:\r\nNeutral\r\nQ2:\r\nTotally Disagree\r\nQ3:\r\nTotally Agree
  #2                Q1:\r\nNeutral\r\nQ2:\r\nNeutral\r\nQ3:\r\nNeutral
  #3                                  Q1:\r\nNeutral\r\nQ3:\r\nNeutral
  #4
```

Or to keep rows with an empty V1:

```
df1 <- df %>% mutate(id=row_number())
df1 %>% separate(V1,c("a","b","c"),sep='\r\n(?=Q)') %>% 
  gather(k,v,-id) %>%
  separate(v,c("v1","v2"),":\r\n") %>% 
  select(-k) %>%
  filter(!is.na(v2)) %>%
  spread(v1,v2) %>% 
  right_join(df1 %>% select(id), by="id")

#  id      Q1               Q2            Q3
#1  1 Neutral Totally Disagree Totally Agree
#2  2 Neutral          Neutral       Neutral
#3  3 Neutral             <NA>       Neutral
#4  4    <NA>             <NA>          <NA>
```

Comment: Great answer!! 
but it seems to be lacking the TS input: D <- '' for an 'empty' set of question/answers.

Comment: Right. There's no Q2 in df as it is meant to be NA in the desiredDF. As Winpel pointed out, I am missing the 4th row which is all NA all  the way through

Comment: @Romain I edited my answer to add the missing line. But if such a line is important, I suppose that there are other columns than V1 in your table and that probably one of them is an identifier. Such column should replace my identifier 'id' and make the first line of code unuseful.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from Nicolas2, the following solution requires a little less code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
   separate(V1,c("X1","X2","X3"),sep='\r\n(?=Q)') %>%
   mutate_at(vars(X1:X3), funs(str_replace_all(., "[Q[:digit:][:punct:]]", "")))
```

Comment: I do not thuink this is the answer, since TS made a mistake i the desired output (or in the source-data). C <- 'Q1:\r\nNeutral\r\nQ3:\r\nNeutral' indicates C's seconds answer should be NA